# How to set initial size of OpenFL window on native targets, while allowing the html5 target fill the entire browser window?

Tags: haxe, openfl

In my OpenFL *project.xml* file, I set the initial dimensions of the window:

```xml
<window width="960" height="640"/>
```

This works great on native targets (`windows`, `mac`, `linux`, `hl`, and `neko`). The window is initially 960x640, and it can be resized by the user by dragging the corner. However, with the `html5` target, my graphics look blurry, and OpenFL is letterboxed with black borders when the user resizes the browser window. Additionally, the OpenFL stage doesn't dispatch `Event.RESIZE` when the browser window is resized.

How do I ensure that it can be resized on the `html5` target like other targets?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the window's width and height on OpenFL's `html5` target causes it to scale to fit the available space, but only visually. It maintains the original dimensions internally. This can cause blurry graphics from GPU smoothing, and it prevents your project from being able to utilize all of the available space in the window. However, for other targets, setting the width and height in *project.xml* affects the initial window dimensions only, while allowing the stage to resize automatically when the window is resized.

You can adjust your *project.xml* file to exclude the window width and height from only the `html5` target, while keeping it for other targets.

```xml
<window width="960" height="640" unless="html5"/>
```

Comment: In my html5 application I use the entire window. I find these settings to be useful:
<window fps="0" fullscreen="true" resizable="true" borderless="false" vsync="false" />
<window width="" height="" background="0xffffff" orientation="landscape" antialiasing="4" />
<define name="openfl-share-context" />
<window allow-high-dpi="true" />